# Log4j Java para procesos batch

Tags: java, log4j

estaba ejecutando un proceso batch que usa un log4j. No sé como es que me sale el logger.info y no el logger.debug si están en el mismo fichero y supuestamente .info es de un nivel más alto.
Código de ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("cambio2");
        logger.debug("----DEBUG--- .");
        logger.info("---INFO---.");
```

Respecto al fichero que utiliza creo que es uno nombrado log4j-nombre.xml No estoy seguro de que sea ese porque tampoco se donde se mira donde coge (ruta de donde coge el xml)

el fichero log4j-nombre.xml tiene la siguiente sintaxis

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC
  "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="as.main.dir/logs/batch.group.path/batch.group.path.log" />
  <param name="Append" value="true" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
    value="%d{[dd/MM/yyyy][HH:mm:ss,SSS]} %-5p %C{1}.%M(%L): %m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
    value="%d{[dd/MM/yyyy][HH:mm:ss,SSS]} %-5p %C{1}.%M(%L): %m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <logger name="es.nombre.services.dao.impl" additivity="false">
  <level value="error" />
  <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
 </logger>

 <logger name="es.nombre.services.dao.util" additivity="false">
  <level value="all" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
 </logger>

 <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
  <level value="error" />
  <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
 </logger>

 <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
  <level value="error" />
  <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
 </logger>

 <logger name="org.springframework.aop" additivity="false">
  <level value="error" />
  <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
 </logger>

 <root>
  <level value="all" />
  <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
 </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Precisamente es porque el nivel INFO es más "alto":
Si tienes definido que el nivel mínimo es INFO, los mensajes DEBUG o TRACE no son registrados. Del mismo modo, si definieras el nivel mínimo como WARN, sólo los mensajes de nivel FATAL, ERROR o WARN serían mostrados, mientras que INFO e inferiores dejarían de aparecer.

Lo habitual es usar el nivel de DEBUG en los entornos de desarrollo o pruebas y usar INFO o WARN en los de producción, ya que además de generar un mayor volumen de datos, esto ralentiza un poco los sistemas.

Por otro lado, comprueba si tienes varios ficheros con nombre como `log4j <algo>.xml`, porque el que has puesto no tiene el nivel INFO declarado en ningún lado, usa ERROR o ALL (todos los niveles)